# Authorize attribute does not redirect to Login page when using .NET Core 2's AddJwtBearer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't make any samples to work when using the new AddJwtBearer. I have a HomeController attributed with Authorize:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I was trying out the new ASP.NET Core AddJwtBearer and I have this code in ConfigureServices just before services.AddMvc():

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(opts =>
{
    opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    opts.SaveToken = true;
    opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysupersecretkey")),
        ValidIssuer = "issuer",
        ValidAudience = "audience",
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    };
});
```

and in Configure method in Startup, I have this just before app.UseMvc()

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I was expecting it to redirect to Login page (which do not have Authorize attribute) so I can enter username and password and then create a token for succeeding use but I always get redirected to a blank page.

I tried navigating Home/Index using postman, body was empty and in the header there is:

```
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is expired"
```

If I use cookie authentication, it redirects to Login page. In the previous version (UseJwtBearerAuthentication), this redirected allowing me to enter a password and get a token.

Am I expecting the wrong behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you expect the wrong behaviour. JWT Bearer tokens are mostly used when calling APIs. It is not very useful for another app calling your API with e.g. HttpClient to get a redirect as a response. A 401 challenge directly tells the caller that they need to authenticate.

If you have front-end JavaScript using this API, you should add a check there for the 401 status code, and redirect to the login page from the client-side.

You can see the source code here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L194

It sets a 401 status code and returns the proper error.

Though, looking at the code, I guess you *could* do the redirect from server-side as well, by using the `OnChallenge` event. Personally I would not except an API to do redirects to login pages.

Comment: Thanks, OK from what I understand from you, I should do the redirect myself based on the response. One question about your statement "JWT Bearer tokens are mostly used when calling APIs": are JWT also used the way I want to use them, not calling APIs but calling Action Methdods from a controller?

Comment: Do you mean calling an action from the same app? In that case, it would be better to just move the logic to a service layer and call the same service layer. If you mean an action in another app, then yes, that would be a typical use case for tokens like JWT.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to figure out how to redirect to a login page, as I was a day or two ago, [This SO post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230596/how-to-redirect-to-log-in-page-on-401-using-jwt-authorization-in-asp-net-core) is probably worth looking at. It works. And I was excited.

BUT!....

My initial excitement quickly faded once I realized that in modern flows that actually *use* JWTs, we don't want to manage the login screen *anyway*. And we can't (from server side) get JWTs into request headers. That's something only the browser can do.

So while the above link was interesting, I've come around to what Juunas pointed out in the first place--that this is not how JWTs are normally used. At the risk of saying it wrong, I'll reiterate that JWTs are more commonly used in OpenId Connect scenarios. In any case, that is where my own MVC app is inexorably being drawn.