# Accessing HttpContext in app.UseStatusCodePages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In my `startup.cs` in the method `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` I want to access the `HttpContext`.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to redirect a [401 response to a login page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231552/5094852).

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)   
       // you may also check requests path to do this only for specific methods       
       // && request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/specificPath")

       {
           response.Redirect("/account/login");
       }
    });
```

`context` in the above example does not have an `HttpContext` property.  How do I get access to the `HttpContext`?

Comment: According to [documentation: Configuring status code pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling#configuring-status-code-pages), that code should work. Only thing being that if not doing anything asynchronous then remove the `async` prefix from the expression parameter.

Comment: @Nkosi the issue is context.HttpContext.Request does not have the HttpContext so there must be some more setup missing...

Comment: A semi-colon is missing in: response.Redirect("/account/login"); The code is compiling without errors.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use UseStatusCodePages(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action configuration) extension method overload.

What you should be using is UseStatusCodePages(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<StatusCodeContext, Task> handler).

Something like this:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context => {
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        response.Redirect("/account/login");
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Then added **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;** statement above my code as mentioned at https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8118. This solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use overloaded method:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseStatusCodePages(this IApplicationBuilder app, StatusCodePagesOptions options);
```

So then just specify your type explicitly and you get access to the `HttpContext` object:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async (StatusCodeContext context) => {
  var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
  var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
});
```