# Redirect to login if is not login aspnetcore 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Need to redirect to login page while calling any methods in project without login. how can I achieve it?

**startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Audience = "xyz";
                    options.Authority = "xyzx";

            });
```

Assume my `home/Index` leads to login page.

**Configure**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
                    {
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "default",
                            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    });
```

for suppose I'm calling `localhost:5555/home/about`(without login) which having `[Authorize]` attribute. now I need to check token is there or not. if token missing need to redirect to login page(`home/index`).

What I find here [LINK](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample/Startup.cs) is  `app.Use(asyn (context,next)){}` calling every time there is chance to check but how can I redirect to `home/index` in that function.

Comment: This post may be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230596/how-to-redirect-to-log-in-page-on-401-using-jwt-authorization-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @Cal279 You save my day!