# JWT authentication and login path

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I have a MVC web application that uses JWT token to authenticate users. It calls an authentication/login API to generate and retrieve the token. Since we are in a single sign on setup there won't be a login page that I can redirect the users to. The authentication happens behind without users knowing based on some information. The only way I have found to make this API login call is by decorating the controller(s) in the web application with an Authorization filter and making the httpclient call to the login API in the filter. Is there any way to configure the login URL globally in the MVC application so that every controller will be protected. Something like the following in the cookie authentication that can be configured for the JWT authentication.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddCookie(options =>
                  {
                      options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
                      options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
                  });
```

Or what are the other places where I can make this httpClient call to the API to retrieve the token and subsequently authenticate the users. Let me know if what I explained here doesn't make sense.

Comment: As you said, you can configure the application to make the HttpClient call to the login API in the Authorization filter. Besides, as we all know, if the user authentication failed, it will show the "Unauthorized" error, as a workaround, you can use the StatusCodePages Middlewre,  if the HttpStatusCode is Unauthorized, you can redirect to the login page, more detail information, see [How to redirect to log in page on 401 using JWT authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230596/)

Comment: Thanks. I read another article https://ignas.me/tech/custom-authentication-asp-net-core-20/ It forces authentication, but even when there is [Anonymous] annotation, it still forces authentication.

Comment: I have checked you provided [the article](https://ignas.me/tech/custom-authentication-asp-net-core-20/), it seems that if add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, it will trigger the customer authentication handler, but, it will allow the anonymous user to access the resource. Do you mean in your application, it will force authentication and prevent anonymous user access? If that is the case, try to post related code in the custom authentication method.